# How to scale a matrix obtained with glm::lookat()?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I am trying to create an orthographic view (separate from the final perspective view).  I know the view's scale, position, it's up vector, and the point it's looking at.  So it seems easiest to simply use `glm::lookAt()` to create the view matrix, except there's no way to specify scale.

Is there a way to introduce scaling with `glm::lookAt()`?  I don't think it's possible to scale the matrix made by lookAt, since scaling needs to happen first to get the 'expected' result (objects appearing larger or smaller, like zooming a camera in or out).  I may be wrong there though.

If it's not possible while using lookAt, is there a series of glm functions that would be equivalent?

Comment: did you try the normal scaling matrix?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of matrix transformations, you can start with a scale and apply the `glm::lookAt()` matrix afterwards. I'm not familiar with glm, but I have used GLUT before. You should be able to do a matrix multiplication like this (I'm assuming that you've already transformed everything into scene space, defined all the variables etc.)

```
    TransformedVector = glm::lookAt(cameraPosition,
                                    cameraTarget,  
                                    upVector) * 
                        glm::scale(scalingFactor, 
                                  scalingFactor, 
                                  scalingFactor) * 
                        OriginalVector;
```

If this behaves peculiarly try swapping the `glm::lookAt()` and `glm::scale()` order.